# How to find places where function will be called instead of search tool in xcode 4.3 lion

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How to find places where function will be called instead of search tool in xcode 4.3 lion?
Thanks!

Sorry my bad english:
I mean that, assume i have a class with name A and class A has a function -(void)findMe;
What i want is find places in my project where the function "-(void)findMe" was called.

Thanks.

Comment: Are sure with "will be", i think it should be "is".

Comment: mmm, i really dont get what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the search feature is probably your best bet. This doesn't exactly solve your problem but you can "command - click" your function, and Xcode will jump to its declaration.

To speed up the search process, you can use "command - shift - F" to call up a project wide search, and "command - F" to search the current file.